# Unable to extract the innertext for the Span title HTML value, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am unable to extract the innertext from 'span title' ( value is  "17L2002131 / Device Type for Electric Smart Meters / DCCI Managed Web Services / **Pending**") attribute of a IE link . Taking the status e.g PENDING for the extarcted innertext I then and want it to paste into an input excel sheet cell where the rest of the data for test execution gets tabulated.

Currently the code is unable to find the **"Title" attribute = "Go To Device"**  and is skipping to the line : **Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "No Activity found2"**  instead of going into the first If Else block.

Below is my VBA code. Could you please help me finding where I am going wrong.

```
   Set objSubCollec = objCollection(0).contentWindow.document.getElementById("tabPage")
   Set objElement = objSubCollec.contentWindow.document
   Set elm = objElement.querySelectorAll("a.pseudoLink")
   Set elm = objElement.getElementsByTagName("span")

     For Each e In elm
             If e.getAttribute("title") = "Go To Device" Then
                 If e.innerText Like "*Commissioned*" Then
                 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "Commissioned"

                 ElseIf e.innerText Like "*Pending*" Then
                 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "Pending"

                 Else
                 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "Active"
                 End If
             Else
                 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "No Activity found2"
        Exit For
      End If
   Next
```

The HTML snippet of the page is:

```html
<tbody class="dataExplorerTableBody" id="dataExplorerTableBody1" style="width: 1022px; overflow: auto; display: block; position: relative; max-height: 125px;" currentsortcolumn="0" currentsortdirection="None">

<tr><td class="grid paddedCell explorerGrid gridFirstColumn nowrap cursorDefault" style="width: 45px; min-width: 45px;" scope="row" nbr="1" listProcess="N"><table role="presentation" style="padding: 0px; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px;" summary=""><tbody><tr ignoremouse="true">

<td style="text-align: left;"></td><td class="firstCol" style="text-align: right;"><input tabindex="5" id="deOption0_zone_1" type="checkbox" value=""></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="grid paddedCell explorerGrid nowrap reg cursorDefault" style="width: 153px; min-width: 153px;" nbr="1" listProcess="N">
<span>00‑00-93</span>

</td><td class="grid paddedCell explorerGrid nowrap reg cursorDefault clickable" style="width: 533px; min-width: 533px;" nbr="1" listProcess="B"><img tabindex="5" title="Show Context Menu" class="imageTypeElement uiMargin oraContextMenuImg " role="button" alt="Show Context Menu" src="./images/alta/popMenuButton.png?ltr" contextmenu="D1_CONTEXT_DEVICE" decontrol="contextMenu"><a tabindex="5" class="pseudoLink" role="link" navigable="" navoptcd="d1dvcTabMenu">
<span title="Go To Device">17L2002131 / Device Type for Electric Smart Meters / DCCI Managed Web Services / Pending</span></a></td>

<td class="grid paddedCell explorerGrid nowrap reg cursorDefault" style="width: 167px; min-width: 167px;" nbr="1" listProcess="N"><span>DCCI Managed Web Services</span></td></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Note that *"it's not working"* is not an error description? Where do you get errors? Where exactly did you get stuck? • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: You use `For Each e1 In elm1` but `elm1` is `Nothing` it is not defined. Please make sure you **always** use `Option Explicit` to avoid typos in variables. And declare all your variables properly. [Edit] and include your declarations into your code in the question. • I highly recommend not to use numbered variable names, they get easily mixed up and you run into errors quickly. Instead use meaningful names.

Comment: @PEH: I have edited my question and have updated some more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `Set elm = objElement.getElementsByTagName("span")` then `elm` will contain **all** `span` tags that exist in your code.

So `For Each e In elm` will loop through them and if it found one `span` **without** `title="Go To Device"` your cell D5 will show `No Activity found2` and exit the sub immediateley.
So even if there would be `<span title="Go To Device">` somewhere before or later in the HTML code if there exists at least one `span` without `title="Go To Device"` your cell will always return `No Activity found2`.

So you must write `"No Activity found2"` into the cell **before** you start searching for `title="Go To Device"` (as a default), if it was not found it will stay by that default `"No Activity found2"` otherwise it will be overwritten with `Commissioned`, `Pending` or `Active`:

```
Set objSubCollec = objCollection(0).contentWindow.document.getElementById("tabPage")
Set objElement = objSubCollec.contentWindow.document
Set elm = objElement.querySelectorAll("a.pseudoLink") 'remove this it does nothing because elm gets set in the next line.
Set elm = objElement.getElementsByTagName("span") 'now elm contains ALL span tags

'set "No Activity found2" as default …
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "No Activity found2"

'… and overwrite it with Commissioned/Pending/Active only if that is found.
For Each e In elm
    If e.getAttribute("title") = "Go To Device" Then
        If e.innerText Like "*Commissioned*" Then
             Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "Commissioned"
        ElseIf e.innerText Like "*Pending*" Then
             Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "Pending"
        Else
             Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") = "Active"
        End If
    End If
Next e
```

Note that if there is more than one `<span title="Go To Device">` then only the last one in the code will be the result in D5 all the others before are over written by that last result.